# jsonrpc service nginx ssl configuration

Tags: nginx, ssl, json

I have a python jsonrpc service running in the server on port 8082.
I want to reach it with php jsonRPCClient. (and have to be https)
My nginx server looks like:

```
server {
    listen   443;
    server_name  service.mydomain.com;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/crt/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/crt/domain.key;
    keepalive_timeout    70;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```

When I type into my browser: https://service.mydomain.com then I see the correct result from service.
But If I call it with php code like:

```
$rpc = new jsonRPCClient("https://service.mydomain.com");
return $rpc->create_client($client_id);
```

Then I can't work with it .. and seems from service log that this time the request never reaches the service.
Any Ideas on how to solve this would be very precious.

Thanks

**(ps: The keys are self-signed certificates, if it changes something)**

The port 80 default nginx setup is

```
server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81;
      proxy_redirect     off;

      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port 80;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }
}
```

And the 443 port nginx setup is:

```
server {
    listen   443;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/crt/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/crt/domain.key;
    keepalive_timeout    70;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81;
    }
}
```

The website is served on port 81 by apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
   ServerName www.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain"
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <Directory "/var/www/domain>
       AllowOverride All
       Allow From All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you see the requests coming through in the nginx log?

Comment: No I don't see anything in nginx log

Comment: Your PHP code snippet simply creates an instance of jsonRPCClient.  Do you actually call any methods from the instance anywhere?

Comment: Yea the ->create_client($client_id); should give back a client id from the server

Comment: That exact code works on http://? Can we see your port 80 nginx config?

Comment: sure .. there you have it